# как использовать шаблон на java android?

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:text="plain text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1111222"
            android:id="@+id/Button1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="111"
            android:id="@+id/Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

у меня вот такой вот шаблон,мне нужно выводить новые элементы на основе этого шаблона, попутно задавая значения для TextView.
так же мне нужно вешать OnclickListener на кнопки и затем изменять их текст
тоесть ArrayAdapter мне тут не поможет.

я сделал программно это, но так мне не удобно подгонять дизайн.

как склонировать этот блок, чтоб был доступ к его элементам?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Опишите саму задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить, а не свой метод решения. Для чего этот шаблон, как и где он должен использоваться и тп.

Comment: как не понятен? у меня есть некий блок, мне нужно вывести таких блоков много, а затем еще добавлять

Comment: Из того, что вы сказали можно посоветовать использовать фрагмент с этой разметкой и добавлять его в активити, когда требуется.

Comment: ну добавлять не проблема,а как получить доступ к его элементам?

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать вот так TextView item_text = (TextView) item_layout.findViewById(R.id.item_text); но программа падает с java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: item_layout это этот шаблон LinearLayout item_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_layout);

Comment: Задавайте вопрос по действительной проблеме. Вы спрашиваете, как выводить блок с разметкой, а потом говорите, что это не проблема и на самом деле вы не можете получить доступ к элементам этого блока. Предоставтьте код, как и что вы делаете, для воспроизведения проблемы и что не получается.